# Hibernate Session factory shared by system database users

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, sessionfactory

I want to create session factory which is shared by all system database users. As session factory is heavy component it is not right to create it every time user login to application.

My scenario is that, I have an application which is login by system database users i.e. Mysql database users not by application users. So I need a session factory which can be created only once and used by all system database users.

Is it possible to do that?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible. you can create a class which have static object of `SessionFactory`. suppose this class have an `static` block so that it will execute only once at the time of when the class is loaded into JVM. In that `static` block you have to initialize `SessionFactory` and when you want to use `sessionFactory` you can call getter of sessionFactory object.

```
public final class SessionFactoryHelper {

    private static SessionFactory sysDBUserSessionFactory;

    static {
        try {
            // initialize  the sysDBUserSessionFactory object.  
        } catch (Exception e) {
            //exception handling
        }
    }

    public static SessionFactory getsysDBUserSessionFactory() {
        return sysDBUserSessionFactory;
    }
}
```

Whenever you want sessionFactory for system database users use :

```
SessionFactory sessionFactory = SessionFactoryHelper.getsysDBUserSessionFactory();
```

Comment: Thanx bro. Let me try your approach.

Comment: I have many system database user. So I am confused by which user I build my session factory?

Comment: No, building session factory is done at time when class `SessionFactoryHelper` is loaded into JVM. so you need not to worry when session factory need to be build it's getting build at application load time.

Comment: Yes, I know that but, the users login after first user is using the same connection used by first user. Is it possible to create new connection keeping session factory as it is. i.e. not building session factory again but just changing connection username and password which is used by user to login.

Comment: Are you talking about mysql username n password? If yes then i guess its not possible to change username n password once session factory get created.

Comment: Just for curiosity are you maintaining n number hibernate configuration files. Like if you have 10 system database users then  do you have 10 configuration files?

Comment: Yes I am talking about mysql username and password. And no I have only one hibernate configuration file which I want to override(override the connection) by which user login to application at runtime without building session factory again.

Comment: @Balkrushn But let suppose some how you get a way to override the hibernate config file then also for 10 system database users you will have 10 session factory objects. because it's hibernate way that it will have one session factory per one configuration.

Comment: So I can't create one session factory with different connections? BTW Is there any alternative to implement this approach? Thanx for your support for helping me brother.

Comment: I guess no,process of creating instance for Hibernate SessionFactory is an expensive operation but if you have limited system DB users like say (up to 10) then you can maintain static map of `<string,SessionFactory>` where key part is username and value is it's respective `sessionFactory` object. But for this approach you have to sure you will not have large number of DB users otherwise application become so heavy to maintain objects only :)

Comment: Okey brother. I have to find some other alternatives. Because I don't have fixed number of users. As you told application becomes heavy, so that I am trying to maintain only one session factory. But, there is no way to do it. :(

Comment: @Balkrushn Okay, In case if you want to know how to change hibernate properties runtime just have a look at accepted answer of this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22200773/hibernate-cfg-xml-modification-on-runtime. you have to modify `Configuration` object before `initializing  the sysDBUserSessionFactory object.`

Comment: Okey, Thank you. I'll tell you if I found other stuffs for this.